# Find the marginal distribution given the mean and the covariance matrix

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

If we have a vector of normally distributed random variables $x^T = (x_1,x_2)$ with mean $\mathbf{\mu}^T = (10, 14)$ and a covariance matrix $$S_1 =\begin{bmatrix}13 & 12\\12 & 13\end{bmatrix}.$$
I would first like to calculate the marginal distribution

**My Thoughts**

The random variables are normally distributed, so the distributions are simply:
$x_1 \sim N(10,13)$ and $x_2 \sim N(14, 13)$? Is this correct? It seems to simple, don't I need to use the covariance?

Suppose now that we assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are returns to financial assets, we need to calculate the distribution of the portfolio that gives equal weight to both assets

**My thoughts**
I'm not quite sure what to do here? Any thoughts? Do they mean that for every $x_2$ we need $\frac{14}{10}$ assets of $x_2$ to get the same amount of money? Any help is must appreciated.

Comment: If portfolio with equal weights means what I think it means, you are asked to calculate the distribution of $(x_1 + x_2)/2$. A linear combination of jointly normal components is normal with $\mu = (1/2, 1/2) \cdot \boldsymbol \mu^t = 12, \,\sigma^2 = (1/2, 1/2) S_1 (1/2, 1/2)^t = 25/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The random variables are normally distributed, so the distributions are simply:
>   $x_1 \sim N(10,13)$ and $x_2 \sim N(14, 13)$? Is this correct? It seems to simple, don't I need to use the covariance?

**That is correct. You could stop here and say if we marginalize over $x_2$, we get $x_1 \sim N(10,13)$. Similarly, if we marginalize over $x_1$, we get $x_2 \sim N(14,13)$**

**The following tells you why you're allowed to say that.**

---

### Marginalization

Let $\mu_k,\sigma_k^2$ be the mean and variances of $x_k$ where $k = \lbrace 1,2\rbrace$. Also let $\rho = 12$ be the coefficient of correlation.

When you want to marginalize, you have to get the joint distribution $f(x_1,x_2)$, which is given to us by the bivariate normal distribution,
\begin{equation}
f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)
=
 \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
 \exp\Big( - \frac{1}{2}
 Q(x_1,x_2) \Big)
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
Q(x_1,x_2)
=
\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}
 [\frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{(x_2 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_2^2}
 -
 \frac{2\rho(x_1 - \mu_1)(x_2 - \mu_2)}{\sigma_1\sigma_2}]
\end{equation}
which could be written as 
\begin{equation}
 Q(x_1,x_2) 
 =
 \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}
 \Big(
 (\frac{x_1 - \mu_1}{\sigma_1}
 -
 \rho 
 \frac{x_2 - \mu_2}{\sigma_2}
 )^2
 +
 (1-\rho^2)
 (\frac{x_2 - \mu_2}{\sigma_2})^2
 \Big)
\end{equation}
and even more
\begin{equation}
 Q(x_1,x_2)  = \frac{(x_1 - a(x_2))^2}{(1-\rho^2)\sigma_1^2}
 +
 \frac{(x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}
\end{equation}
where $a(x_2) = \mu_1 + \rho\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}(x_2 - \mu_2)$

Then integrate with respect to one variable,
 \begin{equation}
  f(x_2) 
  =
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  f(x_1,x_2) dx_1
  =
  K \exp(- \frac{(x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} )
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  \exp(\frac{(x_1 - a(x_2))^2}{(1-\rho^2)\sigma_1^2}) \ dx_1
 \end{equation}
But  $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  \exp(\frac{(x_1 - a(x_2))^2}{(1-\rho^2)\sigma_1^2}) \ dx_1 = \sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{1-  \rho^2}\sigma_1$ so
  \begin{equation}
  f(x_2) 
  =
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_2}
\exp(- \frac{(x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} )
 \end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
X_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)
\end{equation}
In the same way, you would also get
\begin{equation}
X_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)
\end{equation}
So yes marginalizing a bivariate normal distribution is also a normal distribution.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. Do you have some thoughts on the second part of the question? What does it mean 'equal weight'?

Comment: Any thoughts please?